# Issue with gradle library integration with app module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I just moved my `Eclipse Android` project to `Android Studio`, I have an App module, and a Library Module.

The Library Module contains some `3rd party dependencies` in its `build.gradle` as below:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/3_party
        credentials{
            username 'XXXXXX'
            password 'XXXXXX'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.xxx.sdk:'
}
```

Now the library project compiles fine, and it is able to fetch its dependencies from the repository as well, bitbucket in this case.

But as soon as I include the library module in the App module, I start receiving an error wherein the app module tries to resolve the `3rd party dependency`, which should be resolved by the library instead,

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':xxxx:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.xxxx.sdk:sdk:1.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/xxx/sdk/sdk/1.0.0/sdk-1.0.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/xxx/sdk/sdk/1.0.0/sdk-1.0.0.aar
```

**How do I fix the issue with this dependency?**

Comment: it would be helpful if you can show complete package name instead of `compile 'com.xxx.sdk:'`

Comment: cant show the package names, its proprietary 3rd lib, which the client does not want exposed. One thing that I can tell you is that the dependency does not reside in jcenter but in the bit bucket repo as defined in the libraries .gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clone the repo info in your main module.
The main module has to know the maven repo where it has to download the dependencies.

Then add in the `mainModule/build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/3_party
        credentials{
            username 'XXXXXX'
            password 'XXXXXX'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks Gabriele, I had figured this out that day, but got stuck in another issue with gradle dependencies. I will mark this in case other users find this issue as well.

Comment: Although I have one question should the dependencies in the library gradle also be moved to the man modules gradle. Because I see the eclipse gradle export plugin doing it.

Comment: No it is not required as you are using a maven repo. The pom file contains the list of dependencies and gradle downloads these dependencies.